# interopservices v/s normal coding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a form borderless which can be resized and dragged.

Well I got two tutorials to do so [**link1**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C) and [**link2**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13571/Draggable-Form-Drag-a-Borderless-Form-by-Clicking) (and many more).

The first link has simple reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices` with small code and 
 the second one is calling events like `MouseUp`,`MouseDown` and `MouseMove` with big code.

I tried the two codes which are OK to me. As I am not good in C#, I cant determine which one is good based on performance. please suggest me with which I should go..

Personally, I doubt using Interopservices (because I dont know anything about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in link1 uses the libraries native to windows and won't work on other platforms. It may not even work on future versions of windows.

But since the operating system takes control of your form, it requires alot more code to do the same thing using a managed solution, as you can see in link2.

In both cases, you can implement the solution in a base form and inherit from it. Performance wise, link1 would be faster as it does not handle the `MouseMove` event. But I don't know if you would ever *notice* the performance difference.

Comment: Thank you for response. So you are suggesting me to go with link2 because the link1 may not be in future..

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't run into performance issues. It is also more flexible as you can influence which control allows dragging (the choice of a comma separated string is a bit poor imo).

Comment: +1 do you have any link from which I can know more about it (if you have any).

Comment: When you google "PInvoke" you'll get lots of tutorials on using "link1". And if you want to go into details: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries